# SlickGrid Check Box Select Column Plugin "Check All"

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I know I can loop through the rows and get all the id and set the rows to selected via an array.

```
var rows = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < _grid.getDataLength(); i++) {
        rows.push(i);
      }
      _grid.setSelectedRows(rows);
```

But how can i fire the event programatically to check/uncheck the header checkbox which selects/unselects all the rows?

This is the snippet in the plugin JS file that looks for the header box to be checked:

```
 function handleHeaderClick(e, args) {
        if (args.column.id == _options.columnId && $(e.target).is(":checkbox")) {
            // if editing, try to commit
            if (_grid.getEditorLock().isActive() && !_grid.getEditorLock().commitCurrentEdit()) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                return;
            }

            if ($(e.target).is(":checked")) {
                var rows = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < _grid.getDataLength(); i++) {
                    rows.push(i);
                }
                _grid.setSelectedRows(rows);
            }
            else {
                _grid.setSelectedRows([]);
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can select, via jQuery for example, the checkbox in the specific cell in the headers row and set it to checked.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the selected rows as you describe using `grid.setSelectedRows()` will update the 'Select/Deselect All' checkbox in the header row. The 'Checkbox Select Column' plugin subscribes to the grids `onSelectedRowsChanged` event which is triggered by `grid.setSelectedRows()`. When this event occurs the plugin calls the function `handleSelectedRowsChanged(e, args)` which determines if the 'Select/Deselect All' checkbox should be checked and updates it accordingly.

Setting the selected items to an empty array using the following snippet will clear all checkbox.

```
//Select no rows - clear the header checkbox
grid.setSelectedRows([]);
```

Setting the selected items to an array of all items using the following snippet will check the checkbox .

```
//Select all rows - will check header checkbox
//Generate an array of all rows ids from the grid data
var rows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < grid.getDataLength(); i++) {
    rows.push(i);
}
//Set selected rows on grid
grid.setSelectedRows(rows);
```

If you really must trigger an event to check / uncheck the 'Select/Deselect All' header checkbox then you could use something like the below. However I'd strongly recommend sticking to the above methods.

```
//Determine if the checkbox is currently checked
var currentlyChecked = $('#myGrid').find('.slick-header-column:first-child').find('input').prop('checked')

//Set to reverse of current i.e. !currentlyChecked
$('#myGrid').find('.slick-header-column:first-child').find('input').prop('checked', !currentlyChecked).trigger('click');
```

The following fiddle demonstrates this with buttons for each of the methods for selecting items.

http://jsfiddle.net/z83fjth4/